# Use an Input Field In Excel to Lookup and Retrieve Data in Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

So I am pretty new to coding and my work is having me dive into an excel project and was hoping I can get some help please.

We currently have an access database with historical prices for securities listed on certain exchanges. I was wondering if it was possible with VBA to pull the historical prices of select inputs from excel. So far i have this code-
    Sub getDataFromAccess()

```
Dim DBFullName As String
Dim Connect As String, Source As String
Dim Connection As ADODB.Connection
Dim Recordset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Col As Integer
Dim Symbol As String



' Database Path Info
DBFullName = "O:\ProjectX\ProjectX.accdb"

' Open the Connection
Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection
Connect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
Connect = Connect & "Data Source=" & DBFullName & ";"
Connection.Open ConnectionString:=Connect

' pull first symbol input from worksheet
Symbol = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value

' Create RecordSet
Set Recordset = New ADODB.Recordset
With Recordset
' Filter Data
Source = "SELECT * FROM HistoricalData WHERE [SYMBOL] = 'HYD'"
'   Source = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE [Job Title] = 'Owner' "

.Open Source:=Source, ActiveConnection:=Connection

' MsgBox "The Query:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Source


' Write field names
For Col = 0 To Recordset.Fields.Count - 1
Range("B1").Offset(0, Col).Value = Recordset.Fields(Col).Name
Next

' Write recordset
Range("B1").Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset Recordset
End With
ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit
Set Recordset = Nothing
Connection.Close
Set Connection = Nothing

End Sub
```

As you can see, it pulls the data for HYD but I cannot figure out how to have it take values from either a form or cell. I have tried

```
Source = "SELECT * FROM HistoricalData WHERE [SYMBOL] = SYMBOL"
```

and

```
Source = "SELECT * FROM HistoricalData WHERE [SYMBOL] = ActiveSheet.Range("A1)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table must be indexed for this to work.

```
'References set to:
'Visual Basic for Applications
'Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library
'OLE Automation
'Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library
'Microsoft Access 12.0 Object Library
'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.0 Library
'Microsoft ADO Ext. 6.0 for DDL and Security

Sub CustomQuery()
Dim cat As ADOX.Catalog
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim strPath As String
Dim newStrSQL As String
Dim oldStrSQL As String
Dim strQryName As String
Dim myArr()
Dim objCell As Object
Dim lstRow As Long
lstRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

ReDim myArr(0 To lstRow - 2)
'lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim j As Integer
  j = 0
  For Each objCell In Range("A2:A" & lstRow)
    myArr(j) = objCell.Value
    j = j + 1
  Next objCell

strPath = "C:\Users\your_path_here\Desktop\Vlookup.mdb"

Dim i As Integer
        newStrSQL = "SELECT Prices FROM Table1" _
         & " WHERE Table1.CUSIP IN ("
        For i = 0 To UBound(myArr)
         newStrSQL = newStrSQL & "'" & myArr(i) & "', "
        Next i
        ' trim off trailing comma and append closing paren
        newStrSQL = Left(newStrSQL, Len(newStrSQL) - 2) & ")"

   Set cat = New ADOX.Catalog
   cat.ActiveConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strPath

   Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
   'Set cmd = cat.Views(strQryName).Command

   'oldStrSQL = cmd.CommandText

   'Debug.Print oldStrSQL

   'Method1 (Method2, below, needs to be commented out):
    Worksheets(1).Range("B2").Select
    While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Wend
    ActiveCell.Value = newStrSQL

   'Method2 (Method1, above, needs to be commented out):
   'cmd.CommandText = newStrSQL
   ''Debug.Print newStrSQL
    'Dim s1 As Worksheet
    'Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    's1.Activate
    'Set B2 = Range("B2")
    'If IsEmpty(B2) Then
        'i = 2
        'Else
        'i = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    'End If
    'Cells(i, "B").Value = newStrSQL
   'Set cat.Views(strQryName).Command = cmd

   Set cmd = Nothing
   Set cat = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]